# Load Data infile in mysql

Tags: mysql

[image]i need a help regarding mysql query know as load data infile

This is the query which i have actually used.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/xyz/a.txt' IGNORE INTO TABLE TempMobile  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' SET Jobid='23';
```

I have tried both /r and /n but it insert only one row and append the other numbers in the same row.

How to insert the data in separate rows

Following is the text file contents

Comment: Show us 5 lines of your data file `a.txt`. (Click "edit" to modify your question)

Comment: Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html and identify what literals are used to seperate columns/fields in your file. What did you used to export data? What literals did you used at that time? How did you created your file?

Comment: I have already seen the character they are working fine when i use them separately for eg if i use notepad i use \n and for notepad++ i use \r but there is no certainity which compiler will be used for entering the number. so i thought for using same query which will b used for both

Comment: Where is your text file, Atleast I cant see it? What is compiler doing here?

Comment: u can see it now since i was not able to add it i just inserted the images